# Rails 3.1 sub uri assets path issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, relative-url

I am currently using rails 3.1.0.rc1 and when i deploy it to a server which is using passenger and it is deployed to a suburi.

But when I go into look at the site, path to the style-sheets and java-script files are not being included because of the path.

Can someone let me know how to specify the path in the environments so that all the assets (images , style-sheets and java-script ) point to the right path ?

Comment: If you think this is a bug, please file it in the rails issue tracker at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues.

Comment: I am not sure if it is any issue or not. something similar to my issue was posted at https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/2684f17a17e4f97bdb89d20b4cd08585235263a2 but that didn't solve my issue. Not sure whether i am using that right

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed on Rails 3.1.0.rc4. You no need to specify anything for the config.assets.prefix unless you want the change the default /assets.

Answer (score 0):

I got around it using YourApp::Application.config.assets.prefix = "/suburi/assets".  Acording to [issue #1489](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1489), helpers didn't respect this till last Tuesday, so you'll have to use 3.1rc4.  Url's seem to get created correctly, so it may be more of a phusion problem.

Comment: when i tried that the link seems to be created correclt with /suburi/assets/application-XXXXXXXXX.css but when i open the file it says "The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
"